# Rest output field before submit (or after any next submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this form to submit values from an input field to my Flask/Python back-end, if the ticker ID is found in the API GET, it will return a value, but if not, nothing happens, my problem is that the last price will remain there misleading that's the same price for the wrong ID.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formPrice').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        data : {
        input : $('#input').val(),
    },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/price',
        beforeSend: function(){
        // Show image container
        $("#loaderPrice").show();
        $('#formPrice').trigger("reset");
       },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        $('#token_id').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
        }
    else {
        $('#price').text(data.price).show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
        $('')
        }
    });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
</script>
```

I added `$('#formPrice').trigger("reset");` but it doesn't reset the form `#price` field, how can I fix it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try reset the form with below code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formPrice').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        data : {
        input : $('#input').val(),
    },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/price',
        beforeSend: function(){
        // Show image container
        $("#loaderPrice").show();
        // ***** note change here 
        $(':input','#formPrice')
          .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
          .val('')
          .prop('checked', false)
          .prop('selected', false); 
         $('#response').html('');       
       },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        $('#token_id').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
        }
    else {
        $('#price').text(data.price).show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
        $('')
        }
    });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok it did work for the dropdown menu of currency `<select class="form-select" id="currency" name="currency" required="1">` but it didn't reset the ouput field `<p><b id="response"></b>`. Is there another parameter to add?